# How to add Cakephp Cron job cammand in Database cron job

Tags: php, cakephp, cpanel

http://www.myweb.com/dev/admin/reports/trigger_crone/

**reports** is my controller and **trigger_crone** is my action

i want to trigger action of my controller in cakephp

I used following line and command to trigger this page

```
php -f http://www.drvoxx.com/dev/admin/reports/trigger_crone/ >/dev/null
```

can any one tell me where is the problem

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should use [Shells & Tasks](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells.html#console-and-shells) for cronjobs. You probably will need to move your `Controller` code into a `Component`.

Comment: You don't use controllers or components in shells... If you have to it's an indicator for a bad application architecture. The code should be in a model, this way it can be shared (and tests) very easy with shells. See this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18446184/cakephp-2-3-cron-dispatcher/18446486#18446486 and answer.