# How to run cakephp controller action after every hour using cronjob on heroku

Tags: cakephp, heroku

I have made a herku app for cakephp app that want to run a controller action(function) after every 1 hour on heroku. How Can I setup cronjob for controller action on heroku? I am using heroku schedular for run job horly want want to know how to setup cronjob for controller action?

Answer (score 0):

You **don't** call controllers via cron... Use a shell instead and don't instantiate the controller inside the shell. If you think you have to it's an indicator for a pretty bad application architecture and you should refactor your code.

See this question [CakePHP 2.3 - cron dispatcher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18446184/cakephp-2-3-cron-dispatcher/18446486#18446486) and answer.