# How to run a Console programe in Cakephp after 7 days?

Tags: php, cakephp, console

I have a console programe that run only if current day is Sunday and set the target date(Completion date) for that programe next sunday.Now i want to make a programe that run once in a week and set the target date for that programe after 7 days.for example i programe run on Monday tthen target date should be next Monday if run on Tuesday then target date should be next Tuesday and so on.

```
$sunday = Date("D");   
      if($sunday == 'Sun') {
          remaining function
      }
```

I have this logic for my first programe.I am using this programe in CakePhp Console(Shell).Any help for second one?

Thanks

Comment: What you mean is that you want this to execute in a cron job or something?

Comment: i want to run it through command line

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to setup cronjobs in cake php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13949539/how-to-setup-cronjobs-in-cake-php) for your case  *  *    */7    *    *

Comment: i do not want to use cron i simply want to run the progrmae through command line.It is shell programme

Comment: cron are run through only command line

Comment: so you mean that we can not use this logic in our function?Only cron do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `at` command. It is the little know cousin of `cron`. It allows you to execute a command once at a specified date and time, which can be years from now.

From your description I gather you want to execute a script at any time you want, then execute it again after 7 days. This means your PHP script will have to schedule itself to run again. `at` can take an absolute time or an increment:

```
at -f /bin/ls now +7 days
```

Will try to output a directory listing 7 days from now (which will probably end up in /dev/null, but that's a different matter). You should replace /bin/ls with the full path of your PHP script, and execute the `at` command from a system() call (it is not part of PHP itself). It's a bit convoluted, but you can be guaranteed the script will be executed, even after a reboot. Of course, the script will then reschedule itself again, unless you take countermeasures...

When the script is run in 7 days, its output will not be visible so make you sure you either redirect the output or write it to a log.