# Does cron_dispatcher works in cakephp 2.6?

Tags: cakephp, cron

I am having a project which was in cake php 1.3 now it is being upgraded to 2.6 they had cornjob using cron_dispatcher.php setup which is not working  now. Does cron_dispatcher works in cakephp 2.6 or i will have to create a shell task?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to setup cronjobs in cake php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13949539/how-to-setup-cronjobs-in-cake-php)

Comment: A valid question IMO. The cron dispatcher was something in the 1.x documentation that should never have been there (the problems of community driven docs) - it was deleted from the docs as soon as we realized, hence you wont' find references to it now. Don't use a cron dispatcher it's entirely unnecessary. Not related to your question _why_ are you upgrading to 2.6? It would be more logical to upgrade to current 2.x point release (2.7.3 at the time of writing).